# How do I add matplotlib plugin to Qt5.4 Designer plugins?

Tags: matplotlib, qt-designer, pyqt5, qt5.4

For a project I have to combine `matplotlib` with a `pyqt5-gui` designed with the `Qt5.4 Designer`.

The tutorial for adding `PyQtdesignerplugins` version 1.1 doesn't work. Install was correctly build with `pip3` and the export of the `env-variable`s were written to the `bashrc` as followed by a re-log-in.

In `Tools` of Qt Creator 3.3.2 based on Qt5.4.1 built on March, 4th, 2015, I found under `"form Editor" -> "About Qt Designer Plugins"`. Next I get a dialog which just informs me what plugins were found. I can refresh it, but that didn't change anything. 
Since the `PyQtdesginerplugins` which are installable via pip won't be udated in near future, what other ways are there to get `matplotlib` plot within a `pyqt5-gui` without writting the gui by myself?
It's not that I couldn't do that, it's about using the designer properly.

cheers,
Christian