# Qt5 Matplotlib Designer Plugin

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm working on an app using Python 3.6 and PyQt-5.9.1 with Qt Designer for the UI design, and I need to include some matplotlib plots.

After some digging, I found out that in order not to modify the python code generated from the ui file everytime I update the gui part (which is what is expected from Qt Designer), I would need a MatplotlibWidget plugin set-up in Qt Designer.

My problem is that the references I found for this plugin are either from the Python(x,y) package that is based on Python 2.7 and would not work with Python 3.x; or the PyQtdesginerplugins package that is not working either in Python 3.x/Qt5 environment (already pointed out in this question [How do I add matplotlib plugin to Qt5.4 Designer plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512285/how-do-i-add-matplotlib-plugin-to-qt5-4-designer-plugins)).

Is there any possibility to add a MatplotlibWidget to Qt Designer in my Python 3.6 and Qt5 environment? That would help a lot to take full advantage of Qt Designer in segregating the ui from the application logic.

Comment: I have no idea if there is such plugin available or not. But usually you would not need it anyways. You would just leave some space in your GUI and add the matplotlib canvas (which is a QWidget) to it via code.

Comment: If you look e.g. at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391356/embed-a-matplotlib-graphic-into-a-widget-pyqt5) there is a part which is created via some UI designer and a part which is the code to run the application. You would not manipulate the former, but add your widget in the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the promt reply. Indeed it works this way with little extra work. I'll go that path unless someone else know about a magic qtdesigner plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Below you will find a PyQt5 version of the MatplotlibPlugin for Qt Designer.

To use it, put both files in a directory that is either included in your `PYQTDESIGNERPATH` environment variable, or in a "python" subdirectory within one of the [directories that Qt Designer searches for its own plugins](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-plugins.html#the-plugin-directory). The two files must be named exactly as shown below.

***matplotlibwidget.py***:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSizePolicy
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as Canvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import rcParams

rcParams['font.size'] = 9


class MatplotlibWidget(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title='', xlabel='', ylabel='',
                 xlim=None, ylim=None, xscale='linear', yscale='linear',
                 width=4, height=3, dpi=100):
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.set_title(title)
        self.axes.set_xlabel(xlabel)
        self.axes.set_ylabel(ylabel)
        if xscale is not None:
            self.axes.set_xscale(xscale)
        if yscale is not None:
            self.axes.set_yscale(yscale)
        if xlim is not None:
            self.axes.set_xlim(*xlim)
        if ylim is not None:
            self.axes.set_ylim(*ylim)

        super(MatplotlibWidget, self).__init__(self.figure)
        self.setParent(parent)
        super(MatplotlibWidget, self).setSizePolicy(
            QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        super(MatplotlibWidget, self).updateGeometry()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(*self.get_width_height())

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QSize(10, 10)
```

***matplotlibplugin.py***:

```
import os
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtDesigner import QPyDesignerCustomWidgetPlugin
from matplotlib import rcParams
from matplotlibwidget import MatplotlibWidget

rcParams['font.size'] = 9


class MatplotlibPlugin(QPyDesignerCustomWidgetPlugin):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MatplotlibPlugin, self).__init__(parent)
        self._initialized = False

    def initialize(self, editor):
        self._initialized = True

    def isInitialized(self):
        return self._initialized

    def createWidget(self, parent):
        return MatplotlibWidget(parent)

    def name(self):
        return 'MatplotlibWidget'

    def group(self):
        return 'PyQt'

    def icon(self):
        return QIcon(os.path.join(
            rcParams['datapath'], 'images', 'matplotlib.png'))

    def toolTip(self):
        return ''

    def whatsThis(self):
        return ''

    def isContainer(self):
        return False

    def domXml(self):
        return '<widget class="MatplotlibWidget" name="mplwidget">\n' \
               '</widget>\n'

    def includeFile(self):
        return 'matplotlibwidget'
```

Comment: Thanks ! i tried what you stated but i can't get the Matplotlib widget to show up in the Qtdesigner interface.

Comment: How did you set `PYQTDESIGNERPATH`? What platform are you on?

Comment: Thanks ! i tried what you stated but i can't get the Matplotlib widget to show up in the Qtdesigner interface. I've copied the .py files into the designer plugin directory and added the envt variable. Looks line Qtdesigner expects .dll as plugins at least when i go in plugin information box i see only pyqt5.dll

Comment: Windows 10 and i have used system control panel PYQTDESIGNERPATH = C:\Users\thib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\

Comment: @Thib. No, it definitely does not need a dll. It all works perfectly fine for me on linux. Please state **exactly** what you did to set the env var.

Comment: I added the variable both at user scope and system scope. setting as a value the top directory of qtdesigner install. The 2 .py files are located into the designer plugin directory a few directories below the variable path. Then stop restart of qtdesigner.

Comment: @Thib. Those two files have to go in the directory you specified in `PYQTDESIGNERPATH`, not in some arbitrary directory below it. For the purposes of testing, can you create a `C:\QtPlugins` directory, put the two files inside it, and then set `PYQTDESIGNERPATH="C:\QtPlugins"`. If you restart designer, the plugin should appear somewhere near the bottom of the widgets list.

Comment: @Thib. I have now tested it on Windows, and it all works fine for me there, as well. I don't know what you are doing wrong. The steps I took were (1) create a new folder at `C:\QtPlugins` (2) set an envar named `PYQTDESIGNERPATH` with the value `C:\QtPlugins` (3) copy the two files in my answer into `C:\QtPlugins` (using the file-names exactly as shown) (4) restart Qt Designer. If you look in Help -> About Plugins it will be listed as `pyqt5.dll/MatplotlibWidget`. Obviously, you must also make sure you have installed matplotlib and pyqt5 as well.

Comment: @Thib. One potential issue on windows is the unofficial [pyq5-tools package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqt5-tools), which is required for python >= 3.5. In the past, there have been some problems with the `pyqt5.dll` designer plugin it installs. This plugin is needed for loading custom widgets written using python/pyqt5. I only tested using python-3.4 and pyqt-5.5.1 on windows, so that potential problem wouldn't affect me.

Comment: I restarted  everything from scratch sticking exactly to same instruction. Checked no wrong copy/paset for the .py files. Actually i still have same issue of QtDesigner silently not starting. PyQT5 is working fine for other purposes in my app (i've a tableview and listview working fine) Matplotlib also working fine when defining the figure out of QtDesigner. If i remove the envt variable then Qtdesigenr is launching again. Is there any log for QtDesigner where i could a look to get some error messages ?

Comment: @Thib. Try setting the `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS` envar to `1`. This *should* show some output if you run designer in a command window. (PS: if you unset `PYQTDESIGNERPATH` and restart designer, does `pyqt5.dll` show up at all in Help -> About Plugins? The fact that designer does not start when that envar is set, strongly suggests it is actually trying to load the matplotlib plugin, and failing. If so, it would seem pyqt5-tools is the culprit).

Comment: no output with the QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS activated. and yes if i unset  PYQTDESIGNERPATH  i still see the pyqt5.dll. So looks like you were rigth and i guess there's not much to do but forgetting this possibility or downgrading to python 3.4 pyqt 5.5.1. Thanks for helping to clarify.

Comment: @Thib. One other possibility is to install the windows binaries from the qt site, and then compile sip/pyqt5 yourself. Then you won't need pyqt5-tools at all.

Answer (score 0):

@Thib. I was struggling with the same problem but I got it to work. As @ekhumoro suggested, you can put you python files anywhere and then add that folder to the environment path BUT you will need to go run Scripts\pyqt5designer.exe (which is either in python virtual environment or your python installation folder, depending on your setup) if you installed QT designer using pyqt5-tools, which you did based on your path provided above.